# IAM Role for AWS EC2 container service

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, s3-bucket

Q : Is the IAM Role for EC2 instances and ecs instances same?

Scenario: I want one ecs container instance in my account to be able to access one S3 bucket. I went through all the IAM policies but I couldn't find one which allows my ecs instance to be able to communicate to a specific s3 bucket.
As per the concept, ecs instance is in itself an EC2 instance. 
Will the existing role policy for EC2 instance suffice?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your instances to use services you need to configure the appropriate roles for that to understand more about the roles [visit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)